# Nested ANOVA in Python and singular matrices

Tags: anova, python, modeling, statsmodels, nested-models

**TL;DR:** Models with nested categorical factors in Statsmodels lead to singular matrices and incorrect results.

I am trying to specify a nested model in the Python Statsmodels formula API to describe the following simple dataset from Rasch (2019) <sup>1</sup>

| A1 | A1 | A1 | A1 | A2 | A2 | A2 | A2 | A3 | A3 | A3 | A3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **B11** | **B12** | **B13** | **B14** | **B21** | **B22** | **B23** | **B24** | **B31** | **B32** | **B33** | **B24** |
| 30 | 0 | 7 | 28 | 24 | 14 | 20 | 20 | 14 | 14 | 18 | −25 |
| −19 | 20 | 5 | 15 | 16 | 11 | 18 | −12 | −18 | 8 | 16 | 13 |
| −31 | 32 | 3 | 20 | −18 | 27 | 8 | 0 | 33 | −19 | 7 | 36 |
| −14 | 11 | −5 | 20 | 11 | 11 | 32 | −5 | −9 | 6 | −4 | 18 |
| −14 | 13 | 8 | −48 | −10 | 8 | −25 | 44 | −7 | −38 | 21 | −7 |

where factor **B<sub>(ij)</sub>** is nested in **A<sub>(i)</sub>**. My attempt below runs without errors,

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

nobs = 5
nB = 4
nA = 3
A = [f"A{i}" for i in range(1,nA+1) for h in range(nobs*nB)]
B = [f"B{i}{j}" for i in range(1,nA+1) for j in range(1,nB+1) for h in range(nobs)]
obs = list(range(5))*nA*nB

data = (30,-19,-31,-14,-14,0,20,32,11,13,7,5,3,-5,8,28,15,20,20,-48,
       24,16,-18,11,-10,14,11,27,11,8,20,18,8,32,-25,20,-12,0,-5,44,
       14,-18,33,-9,-7,14,8,-19,6,-38,18,16,7,-4,21,-25,13,36,18,-7)

df = pd.DataFrame(data ={
    "A": A,
    "B": B,
    "Observation_number": obs,
},dtype="category")
df = df.join(pd.Series(data=data,name="y"))

model = smf.ols("y ~ A + A:B",data=df).fit()
anova_df = sm.stats.anova_lm(model)
```

but the outcome of the ANOVA doesn't make sense, in particular the cross effect **A:B** has 33 degrees of freedom.

```
            df        sum_sq     mean_sq         F    PR(>F)
A          3.0   2506.300000  835.433333  2.180719  0.102465
A:B       33.0  10338.241297  313.280039  0.817750  0.726097
Residual  48.0  18388.800000  383.100000       NaN       NaN
```

Looking at the regression summary I can see the condition number of the model matrix is 7.77e16 and indeed Statsmodels warns me that

> [2] The smallest eigenvalue is 4.14e-33. This might indicate that there are
> strong multicollinearity problems or that the design matrix is singular.

This means that Statsmodels crossed the A and B factors, and obviously cross-factors **A<sub>1</sub>*B<sub>2x</sub>** etc. are going to be all-zero columns, leading to a singular matrix.

I tried bypassing the `formula.api.ols` interface and use instead `patsy.dmatrices` + `api.OLS`, allowing me to drop the all-zero cross-factors on the DataFrame in between; unfortunately, this doesn't work well with the `design_info` object that's exchanged between patsy and Statsmodels, leading to this error when I run `anova_lm`:

```
'PandasData' object has no attribute 'design_info'
```

Conversely, I know `R` automatically drops columns in the model matrix to avoid multicollinearity.

**Question:** how do I correctly specify nested 2-and-more-way models in Python Statsmodels in a way which avoids these issues?

---

<sup>1</sup> Rasch, Dieter, Rob Verdooren, and Jürgen Pilz. Applied Statistics: Theory and Problem Solutions with R. John Wiley & Sons, 2019.